# Submanifold generators that correspond to Stiefel Whitney class of $\mathbb{RP}^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, geometric-topology, characteristic-classes

Here let me write the real projective space  $\mathbb{RP}^n \equiv RP^n$.

I computed that

$$w_1(RP^5)=0,$$

$$w_2(RP^5) \in H^2(RP^5, Z_2) \neq 0,$$
thus it is non-zero.

$$w_3(RP^5)=0,$$

$$w_4(RP^5)  \in H^4(RP^5, Z_2) \neq 0,$$ thus it is non-zero.

$$w_k(RP^5)  = 0$$ for $k \geq 5.$

> (1). What are the 2-dimensional sub-manifold generators (or its Poincaré dual 3-sub-manifold) for $w_2(RP^5) \in H^2(RP^5, Z_2)$?
>
> (2). What are the 4-dimensional sub-manifold generators (or its Poincaré dual 1-sub-manifold) for $w_4(RP^5) \in H^4(RP^5, Z_2)$?

Are the answers, $RP^2$ and $RP^4$ respectively, or something else?

Comment: Representatives of homology of $\mathbb{RP}^n$ in each dimension $k$ are given by $\mathbb{RP}^k\subset \mathbb{RP}^n$.

Comment: @Cheerful Parsnip, thanks this is helpful - if this is true then you can write an answer and give some Refs/ thanks!

Comment: It follows from looking at the cellular chain complex for $\mathbb{RP}^n$. With $\mathbb Z_2$ coefficients, all boundary maps are $0$.